# Related Rates (Shadows)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, applications

Let me first apologize for what must be the $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ th related rates question on this site, but I really have no idea how to tackle this. From Keisler's "Elementary Calculus":

[Problem 3.2.11. Answer: -120 mph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51sPe.png)

I have an inkling that you will need to use the Pythagorean Theorem at some point, but what I don't see is where do we get enough information to even apply the theorem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. The are two right triangles that are similar. One has a leg of length $10$ and the other has the corresponding leg of length $30-10=20=2\cdot 10$.

Comment: **facepalm** :( would [this](http://content.screencast.com/users/thedarkherald/folders/Jing/media/89e333dc-4448-42b7-a5e1-131a47557351/2016-10-27_2353.png) be the way to solve it?

Comment: @Jorge Medina Yes! At the end the sign of the velocity of the shadow should be minus because it goes in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess I was focused on the big triangle (the one with base 30) and just couldn't see the relationship between the two little ones. I swear, this problem had me on a mental block for days.

Comment: @Jorge Medina You are welcome.